# cplex java variable access from other class

Tags: java, cplex

I'm using cplex in Java and I want to access the value of a variable from another class 
(after solving).

My program configuration class which should print the variable p15[i][j][q] looks like this:

```
import [...]
public class Ausführung {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
try{
            String filename = "[...]
            Data data = new Data(filename);

            IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
            IloNumVar[][][] w = new IloIntVar[n][n][n]; 

            MainTSP.buildModel(cplex, data, w);

            if(cplex.solve()){
            for(int q=0; q< data.distance1.length-1; q++){
                for(int ii=0; ii<data.distance1.length; ii++){
                    for(int j=0; j<data.distance1.length; j++){
                       if(cplex.getValue(p15[i][j][q]) >= 1) System.out.println("p15");
                    }
                }
            }
            cplex.end();
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

The variable is initialized in my main program class like this:

```
public class MainTSP {
    static void buildModel(IloMPModeler model, Data data, IloNumVar[][][] w) throws IloException{

    IloNumVar[][][] p15 = new IloIntVar[n][n][n];           
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                for(int q=0; q<n; q++){
                    p15[i][j][q] = model.intVar(lb, ub);
                }
            }
        }
[...]
```

Unfortunatly the error message: "p15 cannot be resolved to a variable" occurs in the configuration class.
Is that because the variable is initialized in another class?

What would be the most elegant way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a `static` variable declared in another class using the syntax `OtherClass.p15`. If the variable is an instance variable (no `static` keyword in the declaration), then you need an instance of the other class to access the variable:

```
OtherClass thing = . . .;
. . . cplex.getValues(thing.p15[i][j][q]) . . .
```

In both cases, you will need to ensure that the variable has the right [access qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) so that the referencing code can access it.

Without knowing more about your overall software structure, it's hard to say what the "most elegant" way would be to address the problem.

EDIT: After your edit, I think I see the problem. The local variable `p15` ceases to exist (goes out of scope) when the method `buildModel` returns. You need to store the array somewhere that stays around. The simplest change, I think, would be to modify your `MainTSP` class to look like this:

```
public class MainTSP {
    static IloNumVar[][][] p15;

    static void buildModel(IloMPModeler model, Data data, IloNumVar[][][] w) throws IloException{

        p15 = new IloIntVar[n][n][n];           
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                for(int q=0; q<n; q++){
                    p15[i][j][q] = model.intVar(lb, ub);
                }
            }
        }
[...]
```

Then in your `main` method of class `Ausführung`, you can access it like

```
. . .
if(cplex.getValue(MainTSP.p15[i][j][q]) >= 1) . . .
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason to make `p15` an instance field. (If for some other reason you needed it to be an instance field, you would then need to create an instance of `MainTSP` using something like `MainTSP tsp = new MainTSP();`.)

An alternative would be to make `buildModel` return `p15` and then you could assign the return value to another variable named `p15` in your `Ausführung` class:

```
public class MainTSP {

    static IloNumVar[][][] buildModel(IloMPModeler model, Data data, IloNumVar[][][] w) throws IloException{

        p15 = new IloIntVar[n][n][n];           
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                for(int q=0; q<n; q++){
                    p15[i][j][q] = model.intVar(lb, ub);
                }
            }
        }
        return p15;
[...]
```

Then:

```
IloNumVar[][][] p15 = MainTSP.buildModel(cplex, data, w);
```

(Perhaps that's what you planned to do with the `w` parameter? Perhaps simply replace `p15` with `w` in `buildModel` will solve your problem.)

Comment: I added some more information about the program structure. How exactly do I create an instance of the other class?

Comment: @Hendrik - That helps. I added some code to my answer suggesting a couple of different ways to deal with this.